# Split the words using string tokenizer if it is followed by two or more space/whitespace in java?

Tags: java, split, tokenize, stringtokenizer

In my string, i want to tokenize string on the basis of two or more spaces.

E.x.

```
String str = "I am  Chaitanya Gadam.      Split   this string."
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    System.out.println("==Token== : "+token);
}
```

I am getting out put as :

```
==Token== : [I]
==Token== : [am]
==Token== : [Chaitanya]
==Token== : [Gadam.]
==Token== : [split]
==Token== : [this]
==Token== : [string.]
```

But desired Output should be :

```
==Token== : [I am]
==Token== : [Chaitanya Gadam.]
==Token== : [split]
==Token== : [this string.]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `regex` in the `String.split(regex)` method.

```
String[] tokens = str.split("  +");
```

**Update:-**

If you need to remove the leading and trailing white spaces, `trim()` it and then split your String.

```
str = str.trim();
```

Comment: Another problem is that if my string have extra white space at the begining then i get output as, final String src = " I am Chaitanya Gadam. Split this srting."; [, I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]

Comment: but reqiured output is [I am, Chaitanya Gadam., Split, this srting.]   

So i am trying to use string tokenizer.

Comment: Check my update. Use `trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
    String[] array = str.split("\\s{2,}");
    for (String word : array) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```